# trying to restore backup files

Tags: command-line, backup, restore, deja-dup

This is what I get when I try to restore files:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1488, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1337, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1370, in do_backup
    globals.archive_dir).set_values()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 697, in set_values
    self.get_backup_chains(partials + backend_filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 819, in get_backup_chains
    map(add_to_sets, filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 809, in add_to_sets
    if set.add_filename(filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 100, in add_filename
    (self.volume_name_dict, filename)
AssertionError: ({1: 'duplicity
```

After this is the list of backup files.  I did a complete backup and then upgraded from 32bit 14.04 to 64 bit.  I guess I thought I could just use the backup to get my files back but obviously it doesn't work that way.  By reading and googling this problem I feel that it is possible to get my documents and pictures back but I don't understand the coding language enough to do it.

I managed to get some of the files into a multivolume snapshot.  How do I open them or deencrpyt them?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Duplicity. The place to look for those is https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity but I can't find this specific error (search for AssertionError). The proper thing to do would be to report this bug. Include the full command that raised this error, and ask if anyone knows a workaround.

Comment: No the bug is in my ability to write the command to restore the files.  How do I write the command to restore a certain volume of the backup files?

Comment: See http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html - use the `--archive-dir` parameter perhaps?

Comment: I tried --ignore-errors. same result.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, I just blindly commented out the offending assert and it worked like magic!

So modify `/usr/bin/duplicity` and comment out line 1370 and run again and it should be fine.